# Pyspark.ml.classification or Regression algorithms has param ‘Maxiter’ what does it do？

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

What is the role of Param ***MaxIter***?
Is it the maximum number of iterations to run the optimization algorithm?
If so, how can I get the iteration while the algorithm is running?

for example:

```
lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=5, regParam=0.0, solver="normal", weightCol="weight")

model = lr.fit(df)
```

The Maxiter is 5

I want to return the Iteration = 2 when **lr** is running on its second iteration.

Comment: It is the maximum number of iterations to perform before giving up. That is useful since a linear regression does not always converge.

Comment: Just set maxIter=2